# The format-trans problem in using Redis as the second-level caches of MyBatis in spring project

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, mybatis

There is one sql in my mapper:

```
@Select("select count(*) from passages where area = #{area}")
public int searchOilInfo(@Param("area") StringBuilder area);
```

I executed this:

```
int res = oilInfoDAO.searchOilInfo(new StringBuilder("xxx"));
```

The console told me that:

```
class org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheKey cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
 (org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheKey is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I made this implementation of the interface `Cache` like following:

```
public class RedisMybatisCache implements Cache {
    private final String id;
//    private static StringRedisTemplate template;
    private static RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template;


    public RedisMybatisCache(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static void setRedisTemplate(RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate) {
        RedisMybatisCache.template = redisTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public void putObject(Object k, Object v) {
        template.opsForValue().set(k, v, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getObject(Object o) {
        return template.opsForValue().get(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Object removeObject(Object o) {
        return template.delete(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        template.execute((RedisCallback<Void>) collection -> {
            collection.serverCommands().flushDb();
            return null;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(template.execute(RedisServerCommands::dbSize)).intValue();
    }
}
```

this error happaned in `getObject()`, after searching I knew that the data in the second-level cache must be serializable, so I changed String to StringBuilder, nothing changed.

Maybe something happened in my `getObject()` method? But the similar error did not happen in other sql executions.

Weird.

XD

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking and I don't know much about Redis nor RedisTemplate, but if the error occurs when calling `template.opsForValue().get(o)`, that means the `get()` method expects `String` parameter, not `Object`. MyBatis passes  `org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheKey` when calling `org.apache.ibatis.cache.Cache#putObject()`.

Comment: Yes I know that, but even I used the official implementation from mybatis.RedisCache there is the same error, but what you said is totally right and I learnt that, tkx

Comment: If you can create a small project that reproduces the issue with the official mybatis-redis implementation, you should file a report on the [tracker](https://github.com/mybatis/redis-cache/issues). As the project currently relies on contribution from users, it might take some time before someone takes a look at it, though.